# Backing up Windows 7 Active Directory configuration

Tags: windows-7, backup, active-directory

I have some computers linked to company X's Active Directory within my company.

How do I backup the AD configuration on Windows 7 so that I can reformat the drives and restore the AD configuration without having to call company X to come and rejoin my computers with their AD?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unless you are the Admin of the domain this isn't possible.  You could create an exact duplicate and migrate it to another machine.  **You could also ask Company X for advice.**

Comment: why do you need to reformat the machines?

Comment: Ramjound, I can elevate my permissions temporarily. How would the backup be done in this case?