# Back up Windows 10 Active Directory machine password

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

I am the (interim) administrator responsible for a number of shared workspaces. I need to do some extensive updates. I usually perform changes on one "source" system and then distribute the NTFS image to all other "target" machines. All machines are part of an Active Directory with roaming user profiles.

The Active Directory is much larger than the department I am responsible for. Management decided that the Active Directory is administrated by an external contractor. They must not be bothered to keep costs low. I do not have administrative rights on the Active Directory, only for the local machines.

As far as I understand, every machine has a distinct machine password randomly generated while joining the Active Directory and changed on a regular interval. I am looking for a way to back up this particular machine password so I can overwrite the installation with the generic image and then re-institute the specific password. Since all machines are already part of the Active Directory, I expect no other differences between the machines. [This article](https://blog.joeware.net/2012/09/12/2590/) says:

> Computers store their domain password in their “secrets” storage portion of the registry.

So I assume I can access it somehow.

I could of course perform the upgrades on each machine individually, but that would take an insane amount of time.

This is a variation of [Backing up Windows 7 Active Directory configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/550726/backing-up-windows-7-active-directory-configuration), but without a complete re-install.

Comment: Easiest way is to boot the newly imaged machines without network, rename the machine to its correct name, then reboot and rejoin the domain. You need a reboot anyway, as you need to change the machine name back.

Comment: The machines are configured to change their name based on their assigned DNS name and then reboot automatically. So that problem is solved. How can I make a machine rejoin the domain without having being a domain administrator?

Comment: “password randomly generated while joining the Active Directory and changed on a regular interval.” - This does not seem right, and if you have Administrator permissions on the domain on the machines, it means you have permissions on the server itself or do you mean you have local administration permissions only

Comment: [This article](http://stef.thewalter.net/how-to-join-active-directory-domains.html) made me think machine passwords were randomly generated. I do not have admin permissions in the domain. I have local administration permissions only.

Comment: @Ramhound: It is actually how domain joins work – creating a machine account is the main part of the join process; it lets the machine access AD services autonomously. The machine itself initiates the password change (there's a GPO to adjust it). The automatic change is not mandatory but it's still the kind of thing where if someone asks "how to disable this" you go "wait a moment, what's going on"...

Comment: Hermann: I'm not sure about your "configured to change their name based on their assigned DNS name" though. How was this implemented? Does it perform a whole new domain join, or does it actually rename the existing account? What credentials are they using to create that new account in AD – are you shipping domain admin creds in each machine?

Comment: The important thing is that the computers don't simply have a "machine password" – they have a whole *machine account* named after the hostname, which then has a password. If those computers gain new hostnames, there must be AD accounts corresponding to those hostnames – just setting the password is useless if there's no matching account.

Comment: @user1686 All machines have joined the domain at least once. For this reason, a machine account exists on the domain controller for each machine.

Comment: @user1686 After booting, the machine is assigned an IP-address via DHCP. In a scheduled task, a script uses the IP-address in a PTR record query against the AD's DNS server to obtain the hostname the machine should have and sets it via `(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename(…)`. This happened after the image was distributed the first time and before the machines were added to the domain.
Now I do not have any control over the domain controller, DHCP or DNS. I only have full access to the local machines.

Comment: @user1686 - I am familiar with the process.  I admit it's been a few years.

Comment: Reimaging a machine without domain admin credentials simply doesn't work. Even if you were able to backup the machine account PW, you would not be allowed to set it without domain admin rights. This is actually a good thing.

Comment: @EugenRieck Whether it is a good thing or not is debatable, but probably more appropriate for security.SE. On Linux (with e.g. Kerberos or certificate-based authentication) I can totally back up keytabs or private keys. Can you elaborate why it "simply doesn't work" on Windows? Feel free to post it as an answer. Then I have an authoritative quote on why I cannot do my work under the imposed restrictions.